# Mysterious serial port behavior

Tags: haskell, io, serial-port, operator-precedence

I'm trying to write a command line utility in Haskell (first serious program in Haskell) to query a sensor connected to an arduino over a serial port. The relevant portion of the code is as follows:

```
-- Read a single reading from the serial port
recursiveread :: SerialPort -> B.ByteString -> IO B.ByteString
recursiveread s acc sent = do 
    recd <- recv s 1000
    if ((B.pack "Done\r\n") `B.isSuffixOf` acc)
        then return acc 
        else recursiveread s $ B.append acc recd

-- Read a single reading from the serial port
getSingleRead :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getSingleRead path = do
    s <- openSerial path defaultSerialSettings 
    send s $ B.pack "1"
    acc <- recursiveread s B.empty
    closeSerial s
    return $ (lines . B.unpack) acc


-- Checks if the filepath exists, and prints a single reading
readspr :: [FilePath] -> IO ()
readspr [path] = do 
    exists <- doesFileExist path 
    case exists of  
        False -> putStrLn "No device found"
        True -> getSingleRead path >>= (mapM_ putStrLn)
```

The dispatch function (not shown) calls `readspr` and uses a `"/dev/cu.modem1421"` as a parameter. 
The problem I'm having I suspect has to do with order of evaluation. The expected behavior is to receive a frame of data like this, which I check for "Done" as the terminator:

```
T: 33697
Data
0:3.2967772483
1:3.2967772483
2:3.2967772483
...
126:3.2967772483
127:3.2967772483
Done
```

Here is the problem:

1) When I run this code by itself after compiling, from Bash - the program computes for a second and hangs - no output.
2) However when I go into `ghci` and open a serial port with the `openSerial :: FilePath -> SerialPort` command, and then run the program **in Bash** I do see the expected output. (Shouldn't I get resource busy here or something? If I open the connection using `screen` I do get that error)

This behavior is repeatable - I can `closeSerial` in `ghci` and go back to no output in Bash.

Prior research / additional background:

I'm using the `System.Hardware.SerialPort` library (serialport-0.4.7: Cross platform serial port library in cabal) on an OS X machine. There is an issue pertaining to the blocking / non-blocking nature of the serial port on OS X that is at odds with the UNIX standard - [Issue 13 on Github for serialport-0.4.7](https://github.com/jputcu/serialport/issues/13). However, I'm unable to make much sense of it. Any help on making sense of this problem is highly appreciated. Is this an issue with my misreading of Haskell's laziness, or am I missing something on the order of evaluation, where the port is being closed before I can read it fully, or with the library? (in which case I should post it on the Github page?)

Further research: (case solved)

Here's the problem - Arduino resets when a serial connection is opened (can be disabled). When I opened a connection with the program - it would receive the communication from the host before it booted up. I noticed this when observing the LEDs on the Arduino in the two separate cases - opening (and holding) the port in `ghc` allowed for enough time to elapse between the second open-and-read.

The solution was to add a delay of a couple seconds after opening the port - now  "it just works"!

Comment: Is the `defaultSerialSettings` completely matching your device needs ? (speed, data bits, stop bit, parity etc.)
[For my Minitel project, I set up two threads with queues](https://github.com/Zigazou/HaMinitel/blob/master/src/Minitel/Minitel.hs) with a timeout of 10 instead of 0.1. This allows me to do blocking and non-blocking read/writes (it’s at the end of the source code).

Comment: This is a shot i the dark, but could it be that the serial port library requires the threaded runtime? Have you tried compiling with -threaded?

Comment: Do you mind posting your solution as an answer? That way it can be recorded in the right place for posterity.

Comment: Great post! Would you be able/willing to share your code entirely? I'm trying to code something similar on my Arduino and I'm hitting some roadblocks. It would be nice to be able to compare. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer updated for posterity:
Further research: (case solved)

Here's the problem - Arduino resets when a serial connection is opened (can be disabled). When I opened a connection with the program - it would receive the communication from the host before it booted up. I noticed this when observing the LEDs on the Arduino in the two separate cases - opening (and holding) the port in ghc allowed for enough time to elapse between the second open-and-read.

The solution was to add a delay of a couple seconds after opening the port - now "it just works"!